# entity framework 4 configuration related issue

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity Framework 4 Development,I have created WCF service  to get input from client and store it in Oracle Database.

I have  configured same WCF service on 3 servers, each server has 3 diffrent tables in Database.

For example ,

Service 1 installed on server1 will insert input record into Temp_table1

Service 2 installed on server2 will insert input record into Temp_table2

Service 3 installed on server3 will insert input record into Temp_table3

Could it be possible to configure Temp_table1,Temp_table2,Temp_table3 in configuration file.
Currentlly I have  hardcoded Temp_table1 in code ,because of that I need to publish service thrice 
with three diffrent table name whenever any change in the service logic.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synonyms for tables. see [forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/834181)
In first database:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MyTable FOR Temp_table1;
```

In second database

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MyTable FOR Temp_table2;
```

In third database

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MyTable FOR Temp_table2;
```

In the model use only MyTable.